# Add new fields at the billing address woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to edit my billing address at my website, where i need to **add** and **delete** some others in my account page, which code shall I edit?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To delete** an existing field, country for example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_override_billing_fields' );
function custom_override_billing_fields( $fields ) {
  unset($fields['billing_country']);
  return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you please check below code you can **add**  new custom field example.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields' );

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {

   $fields['billing']['billing_options'] = array(
    'label'       => __('Custom Field', 'woocommerce'),             // Add custom field label
    'placeholder' => _x('Custom Field', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),  // Add custom field placeholder
    'required'    => false,             // if field is required or not
    'clear'       => false,             // add clear or not
    'type'        => 'text',                // add field type
    'class'       => array('own-css-name')      // add class name
    );

 return $fields;
}
```

Comment: How to get the data of the field for displaying it on the order details?

Comment: @svelandiag try this https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details

Answer (score 0):

maybe the best way use `woocommerce_default_address_fields` - is it ?
for example as 
[#5447232](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37733627/5447232)

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'add_MyNewOption_address' );

function add_MyNewOption_address( $fields ) {

   $fields['MyNewOption'] = array(
    'label'       => __('Custom Field', 'woocommerce'),             // Add custom field label
    'placeholder' => _x('Custom Field', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),  // Add custom field placeholder
    'required'    => false,             // if field is required or not
    'clear'       => false,             // add clear or not
    'type'        => 'text',                // add field type
    'class'       => array('own-css-name')      // add class name
    );

 return $fields;
}
```