# How to show the data of the new fields in the WooCommerce billing data?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

How to show the data of the new fields in the WooCommerce billing data?

I have created on the page "My Account" of WooCommerce, in the billing address, two new fields.
These are only visible to certain user roles ('administrator'),

The fields are shown at [checkout in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhBFU.jpg)

1 - a checkbox that has a text label: `'label' => __('I have Surcharge'` (which is the one I need to show in the emails)

This field is created with the following code and

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_checkbox_below_billing_company' );

function custom_checkbox_below_billing_company( $fields ) {
    //Show the checkbox only to users with the role "administratorr"
    if ( user_can( wp_get_current_user(), 'administrator' ) ) {
        $fields['billing_custom_checkbox'] = array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'label'         => __('Tengo Recargo', 'woocommerce'),
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'priority'      => 30,
            'required'      => false,
            'clear'         => true,
            'default'       => 0,
        );
    }
    return $fields;
}

// Save the value of the checkbox in the database
add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address', 'save_billing_custom_checkbox', 10, 2 );

function save_billing_custom_checkbox( $customer_id, $load_address ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_custom_checkbox'] ) ) {
        $checkbox_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_custom_checkbox'] );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_custom_checkbox', $checkbox_value );
    } else {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_custom_checkbox', '0' );
    }
}

/* SENDING THE FIELD IN THE POST*/

// Show checkbox label in billing address
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'show_billing_custom_checkbox_label' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'show_billing_custom_checkbox_label' );

function show_billing_custom_checkbox_label( $fields ) {
    if ( isset( $fields['billing_custom_checkbox'] ) ) {
        $fields['billing_custom_checkbox']['label'] .= ' ' . __('(Tengo Recargo de Ekivalencia)', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $fields;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 'add_custom_checkbox_to_emails', 10, 3 );

function add_custom_checkbox_to_emails( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $checkbox_value = get_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'billing_custom_checkbox', true ); // Get the value of the checkbox
    $fields['billing_custom_checkbox'] = array(
        'label' => __('Tengo Recargo de Ekivalencia', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . ($checkbox_value ? 'SI' : 'NO'), //Add the value of the checkbox in the label
        'value' => $checkbox_value ? 'SI' : 'NO', // Agrega el valor del checkbox en el valor
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

2 - A field to enter the tax identification number of the company, NIF/CIF : `'label' => __('NIF/CIF', 'woocommerce'),`

The NIF/CIF field has been created as follows, but the way it is displayed in emails to clients and administrators fails

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_billing_field');
function add_custom_billing_field($fields)
{
  // Get the role of the current user
  $user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
  if ( ! empty( $user ) && in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $saved_license_no = $current_user->license_no;

    // Add the NIF/CIF field to the billing address editing form
    $fields['billing_license_no'] = array(
      'label'       => __('NIF/CIF', 'woocommerce'),
      'placeholder' => __('B12345678', 'woocommerce'),
      'required'    => true,
      'clear'       => false,
      'type'        => 'text',
      'default'     => $saved_license_no,
      'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
      'priority'    => 25, 
    );
  }

  //Return the updated array of billing fields
  return $fields;
}

/* save the new field and show it in email, checkout, etc... */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'bbloomer_save_new_checkout_field');
function bbloomer_save_new_checkout_field($order_id)
{
  if (isset($_POST['billing_license_no'])) { //Check if field value was sent
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_license_no', wc_clean($_POST['billing_license_no'])); //Clear value before saving
  }
}


add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_thankyou');
function bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_thankyou($order_id)
{
  if (get_post_meta($order_id, '_license_no', true)) echo '<p><strong>NIF/CIF:</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order_id, '_license_no', true) . '</p>';
}

add_filter('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_order', 20, 1);
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_order');
function bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_order($order)
{
  $order_id = $order->get_id();
  if (get_post_meta($order_id, '_license_no', true)) echo '<p><strong>NIF/CIF:</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order_id, '_license_no', true) . '</p>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_emails', 20, 4);

function bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_emails($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email)
{
  if (get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_license_no', true)) echo '<p><strong>NIF/CIF:</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_license_no', true) . '</p>';
}
```

These fields are edited from the user's account page, my-account/edit-address/billing/ and are also displayed at Checkout when placing an order.

I only need these data to be part of the WooCommerce billing data and to be sent along with the rest of the data: Name, Surname, Company Name, Address, etc.

It can be seen on the screenshot. //// admin-Mail

Now they are sent in the mail but outside the address range, as you can see [in the screenshot (administrator-Mail.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z09qQ.png)

But this data is not part of the WooCommerce structure, so it is not displayed when I generate an invoice [(invoice screenshot - bill.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkw3o.png)

What should I do so that these data are part of the WooCommerce Billing address?

Perhaps it could be achieved by editing the WooCommerce structure, but I don't know if this is possible, and if it could be done, how would it be done?

How can this be done in the safest way?

Comment: anyone who want to understand background process that lead the custom checkout field functionality to hear , check answer of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75730742/how-to-show-and-order-some-fields-in-the-woocommerce-checkout-only-to-certain-us , that answer is now used in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 * Add custom WooCommerce checkout fields for administrator users.
 *
 * @param   array   $fields The existing billing fields.
 * @return  array   $fields The updated billing fields.
 */
function custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    // Get the current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Check if the current user is an administrator
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $current_user->roles ) ) {

        // Get the saved license number for the current user
        $saved_license_no = $current_user->license_no;

        // Add the custom fields to the billing fields array
        $fields['billing_licenseno'] = array(
            'label'       => __( 'NIF/CIF', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder' => __( 'B12345678', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'        => 'text',
            'required'    => true,
            'clear'       => false,
            'default'     => $saved_license_no,
            'class'       => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
            'priority'    => 25,
        );

        $fields['billing_customcheckbox'] = array(
            'label'         => __('Tengo Recargo (Tengo Recargo de Ekivalencia)', 'woocommerce'),
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'required'      => false,
            'clear'         => true,
            'default'       => 0,
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'priority'      => 30,
        );
    }
    
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields');


/**
 * Filters the WooCommerce order formatted billing address.
 * @param   array   $address The array of address.
 * @param   object  $order The order object.
 * @return  array   The updated array of address.
 */
function add_custom_woocommerce_order_fields( $address, $order ) {
    
    $user_meta = get_userdata( $order->get_user_id() );
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;
    
    if( in_array( "administrator", (array) $user_roles) ) {            
        // Get the license number from the order meta.
        $address['licenseno'] = $order->get_meta( '_billing_licenseno' );

        // Get the custom checkbox value from the order meta.
        $address['customcheckbox'] = $order->get_meta( '_billing_customcheckbox' ) ? __( 'SI', 'text-domain' ) : __( 'NO', 'text-domain' );
    }

    return $address;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'add_custom_woocommerce_order_fields', 10, 2 );


/**
 * Saves the billing custom checkbox value on customer save address.
 * @param   int     $customer_id The customer ID.
 * @param   string  $load_address The address type.
 * @return  void
 */
function save_billing_custom_checkbox( $customer_id, $load_address ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_customcheckbox'] ) ) {
        // Sanitize the custom checkbox value.
        $checkbox_value = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['billing_customcheckbox'] ) );

        // Update the user meta with the custom checkbox value.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_customcheckbox', $checkbox_value );
    } else {
        // If the custom checkbox value is not set, update the user meta with 0.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_customcheckbox', '0' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address', 'save_billing_custom_checkbox', 10, 2 );


/**
 * Filters the WooCommerce localisation address formats.
 * @param   array   $address_formats The array of address formats.
 * @return  array   The updated array of address formats.
 */
function custom_localisation_address_formats( $address_formats ) {
    
    foreach ( $address_formats as $country_code => $address_format ) {
        $address_formats[ $country_code ] = str_replace(
            "{name}",
            "{name}\n{licenseno}\n{customcheckbox}",
            $address_formats[ $country_code ]
        );
    }
    
    return $address_formats;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'custom_localisation_address_formats', 50, 1 );


/**
 * Filters the WooCommerce formatted address replacements.
 * @param   array   $replacements The array of address replacements.
 * @param   array   $args The array of arguments.
 * @return  array   The updated array of address replacements.
 */
function formatted_address_custom_replacements( $replacements, $args ) {
    $replacements['{licenseno}'] = ! empty( $args['licenseno'] ) ? $args['licenseno'] : '';
    $replacements['{customcheckbox}'] = ! empty( $args['customcheckbox'] ) ? $args['customcheckbox'] : '';

    return $replacements;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_formatted_address_replacements', 'formatted_address_custom_replacements', 10, 2 );
```

---

Test it and let me know for any change or if error occure

Comment: Hello.
Thanks for being there. This seems to work, we just have to change the `\n` to `<br>` in the following line `{name}\n{licenseno}\n{customcheckbox}`and perfect. It has some drawback, a space is generated in "the shipping address" that you can see in the two screenshots, but I don't know how to solve this. Otherwise well. Thank you very much for your support https://ibb.co/j5J1vgN --- 
 https://ibb.co/6Z9zpq8.  In gratitude I will create a reward when the time comes

Comment: @gemita ,  `\n` not work in single quotation `' '` , it work in double quotation `" "` , it's my error , thanks for point it out . i'll update my answer , so use `\n` instead of `<br/>`. it is more right way

Comment: Hi @Yash. I have a mistake. The new fields are only shown to users with the 'administrator' role. The problem is that, when adding these fields to the WooCommerce billing data, the field of `$address['customcheckbox']= "NO No tengo Recargom de ekibalenciah`, is added to all user role types by default. This `'billing_customcheckbox'` field should only be added to the billing data for the 'administrator' role. I've tried to do it, but I can't find the way, I can't get it to work, can you give me a hint on how to achieve this and only add to the billing data of the 'administrator' role? Thank you

Comment: @gemita , i make some change in `add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'add_custom_woocommerce_order_fields', 10, 2 );
` so check that and let me know

Comment: Great, I had a similar solution, but I finally used your example. Thank you thank you very much